# Transform JSON into required format

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, javascript-objects

Here is my input JSON

```
  [
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 21052631.657999996,
                "rendered": "21.05M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 505567,
                "rendered": "505.57K",
                "filterable_value": "505567.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33796589.61000001,
                "rendered": "33.80M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1638886.7959999999,
                "rendered": "1.64M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1227540.6669999997,
                "rendered": "1.23M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MILLIIJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 624,
                "rendered": "624",
                "filterable_value": "624.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "USP"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 19.326,
                "rendered": "19.3"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 656562.255,
                "rendered": "656.56K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 882010439.286,
                "rendered": "882.01M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 56100,
                "rendered": "56.10K",
                "filterable_value": "56100.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 63277400.964,
                "rendered": "63.28M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 100239.551,
                "rendered": "100.24K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MNO"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 46763.176999999996,
                "rendered": "46.76K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "THOUSAND PIECES"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 52889941.824999996,
                "rendered": "52.89M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "rest"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 42168373.635000005,
                "rendered": "42.17M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 176340,
                "rendered": "176.34K",
                "filterable_value": "176340.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 187727583.97800002,
                "rendered": "187.73M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33154.707,
                "rendered": "33.15K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1079,
                "rendered": "1.08K",
                "filterable_value": "1079.0"
            }
        }
]
```

I need to transform json w.r.t parent category and what ever child json elements w.r.t parent to be in one format. All should be dynamic no hard coding comparing with strings.

Need to transform my input json to below sampleformat,

```
[
  {
    "Choclate": [
     {
          null: [
        {
            "2022-05-01": {
              "value": 21052631.657999996
            }
          },
          {
            "2022-04-24":{
"value": 505765             
          }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
          "ABC": [
        {
            "2022-05-01": {
              "value": 505567
            }
          }
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "XYZ": [
        
          {
            "2021-11-09": {
              "value": 33796589.61000001
            }
          },
          
          {
            "2022-09-08": {
              "value": 8000
            }
          }
          
        ]
      }
      
      ]
  },
  {
    "Drink":[
{
          "ABC": [
        {
            "2022-05-01": {
              "value": 882010439.286
            }
          }
          
        ]
      },
      {
          "XYZ": [
        {
            "2022-05-01": {
              "value":56100
            }
          }
          
        ]
      }
      
]   
  }
  ]
```

I tried separating parents and child values in an array and loop it and push. But not succeeded. Please suggest me how can i transform my input json to required output json format.

```js
const data =[
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 21052631.657999996,
                "rendered": "21.05M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 505567,
                "rendered": "505.57K",
                "filterable_value": "505567.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33796589.61000001,
                "rendered": "33.80M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1638886.7959999999,
                "rendered": "1.64M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1227540.6669999997,
                "rendered": "1.23M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MILLIIJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 624,
                "rendered": "624",
                "filterable_value": "624.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "USP"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 19.326,
                "rendered": "19.3"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 656562.255,
                "rendered": "656.56K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 882010439.286,
                "rendered": "882.01M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 56100,
                "rendered": "56.10K",
                "filterable_value": "56100.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 63277400.964,
                "rendered": "63.28M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 100239.551,
                "rendered": "100.24K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MNO"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 46763.176999999996,
                "rendered": "46.76K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "THOUSAND PIECES"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 52889941.824999996,
                "rendered": "52.89M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "rest"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 42168373.635000005,
                "rendered": "42.17M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 176340,
                "rendered": "176.34K",
                "filterable_value": "176340.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 187727583.97800002,
                "rendered": "187.73M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33154.707,
                "rendered": "33.15K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1079,
                "rendered": "1.08K",
                "filterable_value": "1079.0"
            }
        }
];

let uniqueparent = [...new Set(data.map(item => item['parent']['value']))];
let uniquechild = [...new Set(data.map(item => item['child']['value']))];

console.log(uniqueparent);
console.log(uniquechild);
```

But from here, am not getting any idea how to transform my data into my desired json

Comment: `I tried` show code you've tried

Comment: @Bravo, i tried seperating parent and child values.. but from there i am not getting any idea how to make use of it to transform my data into desired output.  Updated my snippet with my code. Thanks for reminding me to add code

Comment: I didn't understand anything! The expected result is very unclear. Where is the second element of given array? How do you want to resolve the elements with same `date.value` value? From where did you get `2021-09-09` and `2021-09-08` in result in `Chocolate` in `ABC`? What do you want to do with elements which `child.value` is `null`? Please give us correct minimal input and correct minimal expected result!

Comment: @EzioMercer, i have just given sample output.. it's not correct number and values .. just format of output i have provided... I need to categorize parent and child and then value inside it

Comment: @yobo I asked another questions which are need to write correct algorithm. Answer them please or edit your question with correct input and expected result

Comment: @EzioMercer, updated with desired output.. Due to limit of body characters, i have added only 2 parental categories

Comment: @yobo Can I give you output without arrays? It will be much easier)) You will be able to use `for in` loop if want to iterate keys. Or you must have array with several nested arrays?

Comment: @EzioMercer i think you provide both options in answers if you can able to provide answer.. yobo will use according to his feasibility

Comment: @EzioMercer, waiting for your response

Comment: @yobo I also waiting for your response to my question

Comment: @EzioMercer, I have a desired result to pass my output JSON to API.. So i need to follow my output JSON only.. Please give me your suggested response, will check from there can i make to my JSON format or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is prefect for me:

```js
const data = [
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 21052631.657999996,
                "rendered": "21.05M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 505567,
                "rendered": "505.57K",
                "filterable_value": "505567.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33796589.61000001,
                "rendered": "33.80M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1638886.7959999999,
                "rendered": "1.64M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1227540.6669999997,
                "rendered": "1.23M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MILLIIJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 624,
                "rendered": "624",
                "filterable_value": "624.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "USP"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 19.326,
                "rendered": "19.3"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 656562.255,
                "rendered": "656.56K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 882010439.286,
                "rendered": "882.01M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 56100,
                "rendered": "56.10K",
                "filterable_value": "56100.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 63277400.964,
                "rendered": "63.28M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 100239.551,
                "rendered": "100.24K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MNO"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 46763.176999999996,
                "rendered": "46.76K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "THOUSAND PIECES"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 52889941.824999996,
                "rendered": "52.89M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "rest"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 42168373.635000005,
                "rendered": "42.17M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 176340,
                "rendered": "176.34K",
                "filterable_value": "176340.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 187727583.97800002,
                "rendered": "187.73M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33154.707,
                "rendered": "33.15K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1079,
                "rendered": "1.08K",
                "filterable_value": "1079.0"
            }
        }
];

const formattedData = data.reduce((result, el) => {
    const parentName = el.parent.value;
    const childName = el.child.value;
    const dateValue = el.date.value;
    
    if (!result[parentName]) result[parentName] = {};
    
    const parent = result[parentName];
    
    if (!parent[childName]) parent[childName] = {};
    
    const child = parent[childName];
    
    if (!child[dateValue]) child[dateValue] = el.qty.value;
    
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(formattedData);
```

This is what I suggest to you if you really need an object in `"date"` property:

```js
const data = [
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 21052631.657999996,
                "rendered": "21.05M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 505567,
                "rendered": "505.57K",
                "filterable_value": "505567.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33796589.61000001,
                "rendered": "33.80M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1638886.7959999999,
                "rendered": "1.64M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1227540.6669999997,
                "rendered": "1.23M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MILLIIJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 624,
                "rendered": "624",
                "filterable_value": "624.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "USP"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 19.326,
                "rendered": "19.3"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 656562.255,
                "rendered": "656.56K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 882010439.286,
                "rendered": "882.01M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 56100,
                "rendered": "56.10K",
                "filterable_value": "56100.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 63277400.964,
                "rendered": "63.28M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 100239.551,
                "rendered": "100.24K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MNO"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 46763.176999999996,
                "rendered": "46.76K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "THOUSAND PIECES"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 52889941.824999996,
                "rendered": "52.89M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "rest"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 42168373.635000005,
                "rendered": "42.17M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 176340,
                "rendered": "176.34K",
                "filterable_value": "176340.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 187727583.97800002,
                "rendered": "187.73M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33154.707,
                "rendered": "33.15K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1079,
                "rendered": "1.08K",
                "filterable_value": "1079.0"
            }
        }
];

const formattedData = data.reduce((result, el) => {
    const parentName = el.parent.value;
    const childName = el.child.value;
    const dateValue = el.date.value;
    
    if (!result[parentName]) result[parentName] = {};
    
    const parent = result[parentName];
    
    if (!parent[childName]) parent[childName] = {};
    
    const child = parent[childName];
    
    if (!child[dateValue]) child[dateValue] = {value: el.qty.value};
    
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(formattedData);
```

This is what you actually want (There is also an result as in previous Code Snipept. You can get it by typing `resultMap` instead of `resultArr` at the end):

```js
const data = [
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 21052631.657999996,
                "rendered": "21.05M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 505567,
                "rendered": "505.57K",
                "filterable_value": "505567.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33796589.61000001,
                "rendered": "33.80M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1638886.7959999999,
                "rendered": "1.64M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1227540.6669999997,
                "rendered": "1.23M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MILLIIJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 624,
                "rendered": "624",
                "filterable_value": "624.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Choclate"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "USP"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 19.326,
                "rendered": "19.3"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 656562.255,
                "rendered": "656.56K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 882010439.286,
                "rendered": "882.01M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 56100,
                "rendered": "56.10K",
                "filterable_value": "56100.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 63277400.964,
                "rendered": "63.28M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 100239.551,
                "rendered": "100.24K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "MNO"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 46763.176999999996,
                "rendered": "46.76K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "THOUSAND PIECES"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 52889941.824999996,
                "rendered": "52.89M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "Drink"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "rest"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 42168373.635000005,
                "rendered": "42.17M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": null,
                "filterable_value": "EMPTY"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 176340,
                "rendered": "176.34K",
                "filterable_value": "176340.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "ABC"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 187727583.97800002,
                "rendered": "187.73M"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "DEF"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 33154.707,
                "rendered": "33.15K"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "value": "2022-05-01"
            },
            "parent": {
                "value": "FOOD"
            },
            "child": {
                "value": "IJK"
            },
            "qty": {
                "value": 1079,
                "rendered": "1.08K",
                "filterable_value": "1079.0"
            }
        }
];

const formattedData = data.reduce((resultTypes, el) => {
    const resultMap = resultTypes.resultMap;
    const resultArr = resultTypes.resultArr;
    
    const parentName = el.parent.value;
    const childName = el.child.value;
    const dateValue = el.date.value;
    
    if (!resultMap[parentName]) {
        resultMap[parentName] = {};
        resultArr.push({[parentName]: []})
    }
    
    const parentInMap = resultMap[parentName];
    const parentInArr = resultArr.find(parents => parents[parentName])[parentName];
    
    if (!parentInMap[childName]) {
        parentInMap[childName] = {};
        parentInArr.push({[childName]: []})
    }
    
    const childInMap = parentInMap[childName];
    const childInArr = parentInArr.find(children => children[childName])[childName];
    
    if (!childInMap[dateValue]) {
        childInMap[dateValue] = {value: el.qty.value};
        childInArr.push({[dateValue]: {value: el.qty.value}});
    }
    
    return resultTypes;
}, {resultMap: {}, resultArr: []}).resultArr;

console.log(formattedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely need is to build a tree. Very simple example with arrays is here: https://typeofnan.dev/an-easy-way-to-build-a-tree-with-object-references/

If you want to work with such structure in more powerful way, you can think about creating class Node that have "data", "children" and "parent" variables and then have some Tree class/functionality, that can work with Nodes to add/remove elements, trace them, print them in desired way etc.